# Assigning a variable to another variable in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have assigned a variable `${WH}` to 22 and now want to assign `${WH}` to another variable called `${W_ID}`. I have tried a couple of things, but none of them seem to be working.

None of below working (used in User Defined variable page):

```
W_ID=${__eval(${WH})}

W_ID=${__evalVar(WH)}

W_ID=${__V(${WH})}
```

I can't figure out why the value doesn't get stored in W_ID. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31).

The relevant Groovy expression which will read `${WH}` variable value and save the result into `${W_ID}` variable will look something like:

```
${__groovy(vars.get('WH'),W_ID)}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Create Variable]

You can put the function anywhere in your script. See [Functions and Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) JMeter User Manual chapter for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You can add JSR223 Sampler language can be Javascript and write:

```
vars.put("WS_ID", vars.get("WH"))
```

This will move WH value to WS_ID variable.

There's an issue if you are using multiple User Defined Variables, later assignment can override previous assignment, try to avoid it. The reason can be found in [manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables):

> Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they
>   are - are processed at the start.